# Why is Windows Subsystem for Linux able to run Windows *.exe programs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the new WLS2 on Windows 10 Home. I noticed that, when I ran "npm", the "npm" from my Windows program files was executed instead of the Linux version.

When I tried to execute cmd.exe or notepad.exe from WSL2, I noticed those also work!

[image]

How is this possible? How is WSL2 able to run Windows executables?

Additionally, how can I force WSL2 to prioritize the Linux executables over the Windows ones in cases where they have the same names?

Comment: Why are you shocked this works?  WSL is aware of the Windows file system.  So why wouldn’t it be able to run a Windows executable?  The NT kernel still exists.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1493

Comment: By specifying full paths. Windows looks into the file to decide how to run it. From CreateProcess - the ONLY way to start a program, _lpApplicationName 
[in] Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the module to execute. The specified module can be a Windows-based application. It can be some other type of module (for example, MS-DOS or OS/2) if the appropriate subsystem is available on the local computer._

Comment: Because Microsoft wanted it to.

Comment: All Windows programs, DLLs, and font files include an MSDos program as well that in the long past would, if run in DOS, start windows and run your executable. Now it just prints _This program requires Microsoft Windows_. Also Windows by default ran DOS files in the OS/2 sub system, not the Windows sub system which could also run them. (Dos in OS/2 was faster).

Comment: Another interesting fact is for files without a Windows' file association CMD.exe will pass it to `CreateProcess` to see if it knows what to do with it. So CMD (but not Explorer) will run an executable (of any supported type) no matter what it is called.

Comment: Please note that he es asking about WSL2, which is fundamentally different from the original WSL.

Comment: Though, I have to ask: Are you sure you were using WSL2 when testing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How is WSL2 able to run Windows executables?

The Windows executable (PE binary) is added as a [binfmt_misc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) entry in WSL2.
In simple words, [binfmt_misc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) is a Linux kernel feature which allows
arbitrary executable file formats to be recognized and passed to certain programs.

In WSL2, the `init` binary (from which every process is forked) register the
Windows PE binary as a executable and make it executable by itself (i.e. the `init`).
Here is a output of the PE binfmt entry:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
enabled
interpreter /tools/init
flags: F
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

`WSLInterop` is just a name for the entry. The magic number `4d5a` is `MZ` which
is first two bytes of Windows PE executable. Assume this is a fingerprint with
which `init` (the interpreter) recognizes PE binary.

Users can disable the registry with this command:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
```

### Further readings:

- [Windows Subsystem for Linux interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop)
- [Wikipedia: binfmt_misc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop)
- [Kernel Support for miscellaneous (your favourite) Binary Formats v1.1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html)

Answer (score 7):

It will run any executable (Windows or linux) that is in your `$PATH` environment variable.  It searches the directories in order, so if you want to run the linux versions by preference, make sure those directories are *before* the windows directories in the path

Comment: why is WSL able to run windows executables?

Comment: Because ultimately your still running Windows.  While WSL 2 is running a Linux kernel it’s aware of Windows.

Answer (score 5):

bash is running as a pico process. When you try to run a program, the linux subsystem driver recognizes the request to run a process and calls `ZwCreateUserProcess` in the windows kernel, creating the windows process.

It can call the function because all system calls made by pico processes are translated into NT calls in kernel mode, both via `LXCORE.SYS` and the kernel, `ntoskrnl.exe`.

Comment: That’s no longer the case with WSL2 though, which is essentially a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [alias](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/bash-aliases) for the Linux apps you wish to prioritize over their Windows namesakes. For example:

alias foo='/path/to/bar'